# How to get a list of "count an entity by an area" in JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to get a list containing the number of an entity (count) by an area (each value existing in the table), in JPA.

I found that there is a method that gives the number of an entity by a given value of an area

```java
 @Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    public int countByArea_Libelle(String l);
}
```

user

```java
@Entity(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    private String name;
}
```

Is there a method that count an entity with all the value of an area or should i implement it ?

Comment: Did I understand right. The entities have a 2 dimensional position and the areas have boundaries? Or are you working 3 dimensional. Could you give us more information about the schema you are using?

Comment: Please post the entity as well for devs to understand your post

Comment: i edited the post, please see the code. I am using JPA repository. For example : count the number of users by their address. I want to get 10 for New York, 5 for Paris ... Is there a method to get a list of "count" of all the value existing in the table (in the example New York, Paris ...) or should i implement it

Comment: Can you post your user domain?

Comment: i edited the post, please see my edit

Comment: i added a query using the annotation @Query and i used a Map as a return type. When i run the application i get the error "query did not return a unique result"  How can i keep all the rows returned from the querying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select new map( count(u.address) as numberOfUsers, u.address as city )  FROM User u  group by u.address")
    List<Object> countByAddressList();
}
```

Comment: can you give me an example for a query on many to many relationship?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
   long countByAddress(String address);
}
```

Comment: I am searching for a method to return a list counting users by every address/city